# Como calcular a média de uma coluna em R?

Tags: r

Tenho um arquivo Excel no formato `.csv`(valores separados por vírgula) e quero ler o que está em uma coluna, somar e calcular a sua média.

Como abrir o arquivo eu já sei, mas não sei como somar os valores para calcular a média.

Desde já, agradeço por sua ajuda.

Comment: -1. É preciso demonstrar algum esforço de pesquisa sobre o tema que quer ver esclarecido. É um princípio básico do SO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Supondo que o data frame que você leu do arquivo Excel esteja num objeto chamado `dados` e que você queira somar os valores de uma coluna/variável desse data frame chamada `V1`, basta usar a função `sum()`:

```
sum(dados$V1)
```

Além disso, você pode calcular a média dos valores dessa coluna/variável diretamente usando a função `mean(x)`:

```
mean(x = dados$V1)
```

Answer (score 6):

**Estendendo a resposta do @Raphael Nishimura:**

Caso o objetivo seja calcular a média de todas as colunas do data.frame `dados`, ao invés de usar um comando para cada uma das colunas como em:

```
mean(dados$V1)
mean(dados$V2)
mean(dados$V3)
...
```

use a função `apply` (supondo que todas as colunas de `dados` sejam do tipo `numeric`):

```
apply(dados,2,mean)
```

Onde 2 indica que o data.frame será dividido em colunas (`1` para linhas e `c(1,2)` para linhas E colunas). Repare que você pode substituir a função `mean` por outra que você desejar, como `sd` para calcular o desvio-padrão.

Answer (score 0):

Se você quiser calcular a média de todas as colunas, você pode utilizar:

```
colMeans(dados)
```

Caso deseje calcular a média de uma coluna específica

```
colMeans(dados$V1)
```

Também é possível calcular a média das linhas:

```
rowMeans(dados); rowMeans(dados$V1)
```

Espero ter ajudado!